# LazyDataModel initial load called multiple times

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I have this datatable which I implemented with Primefaces's LazyDataModel.
Everything works fine except for the initial load when I open the page for the first time or refresh.
The load method get called 6-7 times.

When I change page, filter or sort it works correctly, load is only called once.

Since I perform calls to the database I would like to prevent it to be called more then needed.

I have the following:

XHTML:

```
    <p:outputPanel id="documentsPanel">
        <h:form id="documentsForm">
            <p:dataTable id="documentsTable"
                         widgetVar="documentsTable"
                         var="doc"
                         value="#{MyManagedBean.model}"
                         paginator="true" rows="20"
                         paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {CurrentPageReport}"
                         currentPageReportTemplate="{totalRecords} #{c.NumberOfRequestFound}"
                         lazy="true">
     ...

            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </p:outputPanel>
```

Java:

```
public class DocumentEncodingDataModel extends LazyDataModel<SelectableDocumentToBeEncodedDTO> {

@Override
public List<SelectableDocumentToBeEncodedDTO> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
   ....
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return super.getRowCount();
}

@Override
public SelectableDocumentToBeEncodedDTO getRowData(String rowKey) {
    log.debug("getRowData");
    if (!StringUtils.isBlank(rowKey)) {
        for (SelectableDocumentToBeEncodedDTO doc : currentDocumentsToBeEncoded) {
            if (doc.getDocumentToBeEncoded().getId().toString().equals(rowKey)) {
                return doc;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object getRowKey(SelectableDocumentToBeEncodedDTO doc) {
    return doc.getDocumentToBeEncoded().getId();
}

}
```

Primefaces version: 6.2
JSF version: 2.1

Comment: Could you post the relevant code of MyManagedBean? All references to the `model` field

Comment: Post the code in [mcve] flavour, and also post PrimeFaces version info... And JSF implementation and version.

Comment: I added versions. I checked all model references in MyManagedBean but it still happens. My error is probably in the XHTML. Is that possible?

Comment: encodeEnd method in class DataTable renderer from package org.primefaces.component.datatable is called multiple times which causes the load multiple times

Comment: That is why a [mcve] is requested.